# Will the new SameSite cookie attribute effectively prevent all targeted ads?

Tags: cookies, csrf, ads, samesite

There is a new attribute for cookies called `SameSite` that is by default set to allow `Get` requests for cross-sites to prevent CSRF via other HTTP Verbs.

As far as I know all targeted ads are heavily relying on cross-site cookies. Now if browsers or a plugin for a browser would just intercept all the cookies and set them to `SameSite` `Strict`, would not that effectively mean end of targeted ads? (At least the cross-site type we are seeing all the time now, when you see something you recently checked on amazon being advertised "everywhere" after that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The `SameSite` attribute is not new, what's new is the introduction of an explicit `None` value and the adoption of new defaults described by the [Incrementally Better Cookies draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-00). This means that instead of cookies being sent with all requests by default, they must be explicitly marked for cross-site transfer.

That's it. Mark cookies as `SameSite=None; Secure` and they retain their legacy behaviour enabling them to be sent on cross-site requests as often utilised by advertising platforms.

You can read https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained for more context.

Comment: Yes, this is correct what you write, but won't it be possible to very easily write a plugin to a browser that will set all the cookies to be like that? Effectively preventing all cross-site cookies

Comment: Blocking all third-party cookies is already a built-in setting in Chrome. This change means that cookies now need to expressly mark their intent to be available in a third-party context.

Comment: Thanks for info, did not know it's already allowed. I have turned it on :)